# Table don't change after state change

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have antd table, I am to try to update only a subtable to add one row after api return.

**If subtable is empty the row it shows on the table, if subtable have one row and more table subtable don't change. The problem is with expandedRowRender if i click for sorting the new data it shows there**

But i cannot make a table to add the new row. When i print the new state for data its ok, i can see the new row there, but the table is the same. Any ideas ? i am not sure if the problem is the setState or something else i am doing wrong.

```
for (const property in dataGroup) {
  if (dataGroup[property].id === new.group_id) {
    dataGroup[property].group.push({
      id: user.id,
      name: user.name,
    });
    break;
  }
}
this.setState({
  data: [...dataGroup],
});
console.log(this.state.data);

-------------------------
return (
  <Table
    columns={columns}
    rowSelection={rowSelection}
    rowKey={(record) => record.id}
    expandable={{ expandedRowRender }}
    dataSource={data}
  />
........
```

Table json

```
[
  {
    "id": 97,
    "name": "f",
    "description": "",
    "group": [
      {
        "id": 90,
        "name": "fds",
      },
      {
        "id": 91,
        "name": "dsa",
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 98,
    "name": "fddf",
    "description": "",
    "group": [
      {
        "id": 96,
        "name": "fddd",
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, never use setState inside a loop or multiple times inside the same execution path because it is useless and restricts performance. call it at the end of your function execution.

The reason your state is not changing is because react thinks your state.data variable hasn't changed since it maintains the same reference. You need to use the spread operator to recreate the same object with a different reference.

```
for (const property in data) {
    if (data[property].id === new.group_id) {
        data[property].group.push({
            id: user.id,
            name: user.name,
        });

        break;
    }
    
}
this.setState({
    data: { ...data },
});
console.log(this.state.data);
```

Also make sure to set the key prop for your component arrays

Comment: hi thanks for the reply but is not working :/ dataGroup is array i change it to     this.setState({
      data: [...dataGroup],
    });

but is  the same table don't change, but with print is ok :(
i edit also the question change the data to dataGroup :/

Comment: wb the table code, did u set the table data to state.data?

Comment: after the loop, try this.forceUpdate() to check if it is due to the item references

Comment: i try also forceUpdate after setState but nothing change :( i was having dataSource={data} but change it with this.state.data still the same i have the same function for other and is working great but with out sub table

Comment: i found that if subtable is empty the row it shows on the table